# Universally open and unramified, but not flat

Tags: algebraic-geometry, flatness

A flat morphism of schemes that is locally of finite presentation is universally open, for instance see [The Stacks Project — Tag 01UA](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01UA). I never encountered any reference to the inverse statement, and it seems too much to hope to be true. So, I would like to know if there are known examples of universally open morphisms of schemes that are **not**

1. flat,
2. <strike>locally of finite presentation,</strike>
3. <strike>flat or locally of finite presentation.</strike>

I am mainly interested in unramified such morphisms, yet any such example would be appreciated.

Comment: If $k$ is a field and $X$ is a scheme, then any morphism $X\to\operatorname{Spec} k$ is is universally open, but not necessarily locally of finite presentation.

Comment: @Slade: Yes, thank you!

Comment: $X_{red} \to X$.

Comment: @A.G: Thank you, maybe you add it as an answer

Comment: You're welcome.